# " Missing or invalid parameter value. Please input valid data for all parameters". Telerik Reporting Rest Web API (.tdmx)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have created Telerik rest web API service.

//Report controller c# code

```
public ReportsController()
        {
            var appPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/");
            var reportsPath = Path.Combine(appPath, "Reports");

            var resolver = new ReportFileResolver(reportsPath)
                .AddFallbackResolver(new ReportTypeResolver());

            //Setup the ReportServiceConfiguration
            configurationInstance = new ReportServiceConfiguration
            {
                HostAppId = "Html5App",
                Storage = new FileStorage(),
                ReportResolver = resolver,

                // ReportSharingTimeout = 0,
                // ClientSessionTimeout = 15,
            };

            this.ReportServiceConfiguration = configurationInstance;
        }
```

﻿

//Report viewer Code

```
    $("#reportViewer1")
        .telerik_ReportViewer({
            serviceUrl: "http://localhost:12345/api/Reports",
            reportSource: {
                report: "Dashboard.trdx",
                parameters: { ReportYear : 2009 }
            },
            viewMode: telerikReportViewer.ViewModes.INTERACTIVE,
            scaleMode: telerikReportViewer.ScaleModes.SPECIFIC,
            scale: 1.0,
            enableAccessibility: false,
            sendEmail: { enabled: true }
        });
```

﻿

//trdx Code of parameter

```
 <DataSources>
    <SqlDataSource ConnectionString="Telerik.Reporting.Examples.CSharp.Properties.Settings.TelerikConnectionString" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(OrderDate) AS Year&#xD;&#xA;FROM         Sales.SalesOrderHeader&#xD;&#xA;ORDER BY Year" Name="yearDataSource" />
    <SqlDataSource ConnectionString="Telerik.Reporting.Examples.CSharp.Properties.Settings.TelerikConnectionString" SelectCommand="SELECT&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;P.Name AS ProductName&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;, SOD.LineTotal / 1000 AS LineTotal&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;, SOH.OrderDate&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;, SS.Name AS StoreName&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;, C.FirstName + ' ' + COALESCE (C.MiddleName, '') + ' ' + C.LastName AS SalesPersonFullName&#xD;&#xA;FROM&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;Production. Product AS P&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS SOD ON P.ProductID = SOD.ProductID&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS SOH ON SOD.SalesOrderID = SOH.SalesOrderID&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;INNER JOIN Sales.Store AS SS             ON SS.CustomerID = SOH.CustomerID&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;INNER JOIN Sales.SalesPerson AS SP       ON SP.SalesPersonID = SOH.SalesPersonID&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS E  ON E.EmployeeID = SP.SalesPersonID&#xD;&#xA;&#x9;INNER JOIN Person.Contact AS C           ON C.ContactID = E.ContactID&#xD;&#xA;WHERE     (YEAR(SOH.OrderDate) = @Year)" Name="mainDataSource">
      <Parameters>
        <SqlDataSourceParameter DbType="Int32" Name="@Year">
          <Value>
            <String>=Parameters.ReportYear.Value</String>
          </Value>
        </SqlDataSourceParameter>
      </Parameters>
      <DefaultValues>
        <SqlDataSourceParameter DbType="Int32" Name="@Year">
          <Value>
            <String>2001</String>
          </Value>
        </SqlDataSourceParameter>
      </DefaultValues>
    </SqlDataSource>
  </DataSources>
```

﻿

Passing a parameter "ReportYear" and using .trdx file.

﻿

I'm getting an error "Missing or invalid parameter value. Please input valid data for all parameters."

If I'm not passing the parameter then the report will function properly.

What else is needed for getting the parameter value in .trdx file?

I'm really stuck into it. It would be great if someone can help in to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add report parameters to report, Not sql parameters.

Right click on report and go to report parameter.

https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports-parameters-adding-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got it. I was passing the report parameter as "ReportYear" instead of "Year"

Answer (score 0):

Pass the report parameter as "ReportYear" instead of "Year"